# How does setState() rebuild child widgets?

Tags: dart, flutter, widget

I just need some idea on how flutter stateful widgets build their stateful children when setState() is invoked. Please look at the code below.

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Parent build method invoked");
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            StatefulChild(), // Keeping this line gives the output 1
            statefulChild, // Keeping this line gives the output 2
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Click me'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {});
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  StatefulChild statefulChild = StatefulChild();
}

class StatefulChild extends StatefulWidget {
  StatefulChildState createState() => StatefulChildState();
}

class StatefulChildState extends State<StatefulChild> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Child00 build method invoked");
    return Container();
  }
}
```

When the RaisedButton is pressed,

Output 1 // Keeping only `StatefulChild()`,

```
I/flutter ( 2903): Parent build method invoked
I/flutter ( 2903): Child00 build method invoked
```

Output 2 // Keeping only `statefulChild`,

```
I/flutter ( 2903): Parent build method invoked
```

What is the difference here? What happens under the hood? Detailed explanation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

When the widget tree rebuilds, Flutter compares using `==` the previous and new widget returned by the `build` method.

There are two scenarios in that situation:

- `==` is `false`. In that case, Flutter will compare the `runtimeType` & `key` to know if the state of the previous widget should be preserved. Then Flutter calls `build` on that widget
- `==` is `true`. In which case, Flutter aborts the building of the widget tree (aka won't call `build`).

This is an optimization possible thanks to the immutability of widgets.

Since widgets are immutable, if `==` haven't changed then it means that there's nothing to update. Flutter can therefore safely optimize that.

Comment: "compare using == previous and new widget returned by build method", U mean build method is already called. Then in "== is false" condition again you said "flutter calls build on that widget". Which widget are you exactly talking about, can you please point parent widget and child widget. Please elaborate with a small example.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `setState(())` only the `build()` will get called. Now in this method you are again invoking `StatefulChild()` (first line) which further instantiates this class so the `build()` method of this class gets executed.

But when you use `statefulChild` it is not creating a new instance because

```
StatefulChild statefulChild = StatefulChild();
```

is used outside the `build()` method. So it just got called once.

Comment: I thought that instances structure is kept in memory and only build method is called when rebuilt. Are those classes instantiated whenever a rebuild happens?

Comment: Those class instances will be kept in memory for sure and in your new `StatefulWidget` you will receive a call in `didUpdateWidget()` method instead of `initState()` after this the `build()` method gets called.